# How to get the row count from an azure database?

Tags: javascript, azure, windows-8, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

Am working on a windows store javascript application. The application uses data from azure mobile services. 
Consider the below code:

```cs
var itemTable = mobileService.getTable('item');
//item is the table name stored in the azure database
```

The code fetches the entire table `item` and saves it to a variable `itemTable`.

What code will return the no of rows present in `itemTable`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `includeTotalCount` method on the table/query object (unfortunately it's missing from the documentation, I'll file a bug to the product team to have it fixed).

When you call `read` on the query object, it will return by default 50 (IIRC, the number may be different) elements from it, to prevent a naïve call from returning all elements in a very large table (thus either incurring the outbound bandwidth cost for reserved services, or hitting the quota for free ones). So getting all the elements in the table, and getting the length of the results may not be accurate.

If all you want is the number of elements in the table, you can use the code below: returning *zero* elements, and the total count.

```
    var table = client.getTable('tableName');
    table.take(0).includeTotalCount().read().then(function (results) {
        var count = results.totalCount;
        new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog('Total count: ' + count).showAsync();
    });
```

If you want to query some elements, and also include the total count (i.e., for paging), just add the appropriate `take()` and `skip()` calls, and also the `includeTotalCount` as well.

Comment: Thank you carlosfigueira! It worked :). And  is there a way to do this process at the azure side and return the row count result alone to the client app?

Comment: It would be great to provide a simple `Query` method `.count()` which did exactly this. Something like... `client.getTable('tableName').count()` instead of `read()` to get the scalar result;

Comment: Good idea, will file a suggestion with the product team.

Comment: Any update on how to do this in the current version? I get an error message that then() doesn't exist. I also tried it just passing the function as the first parameter of read, still no joy.

Answer (score 4):

If anybody comes here and interested in how to get the totalCount only on C# (like me), then this is how you do it:

```
var table =  MobileService.GetTable<T> ();
var query = table.Take(0).IncludeTotalCount();
IList<T> results = await query.ToListAsync ();
long count = ((ITotalCountProvider)results).TotalCount;
```

Credit goes to this blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinash/archive/2013/02/13/retrieving_2d00_more_2d00_data_2d00_from_2d00_azure_2d00_mobile_2d00_services_2d00_using_2d00_paging.aspx)

Comment: The `ITotalCountProvider` is marked obsolete, I used `IQueryResultEnumerable<T>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute [`read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554224.aspx) on the [table query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj613353.aspx) and then get the `length` of the results.

```cs
var items, numItems;
itemTable.read().then(function(results) { items = results; numItems = items.length; });
```

If you are only showing a record count and not the entire results - you should just select the ID column to reduce the amount of data transmitted. I don't see a `count()` method available yet in the [JS Query API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj613353.aspx) to fill this need.

```cs
var itemTable = mobileService.getTable('item').select('itemID');
```

Comment: This code actually will not work. The function parameter passed to the `then` function will be executed asynchronously, once the network request completes. That means that the line `var numItems = items.length` will be executed before that, and `items` will be undefined at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply SilverNinja! But in the code given above "items" is still undefined after assigning "results" to it. And hence appending "length" to "items" popped the following error

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

(Note:My Azure DB is not empty)

Comment: Try checking if you are getting an error back during the `read()` operation. Add another parameter to [`then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for the `failFilter`...`.then(function(results){...}, function(){ alert("$.read failed!");)`

Comment: It's not a matter of error - even if the call succeeds, you'll still have the `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference` error. If you moved that line to the function, then it would stop giving this error, but, as shown in my other answer, it would still not work in the general case.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Thanks for the pointer - I've added it into the function, but your "internal" capability (**includeTotalCount**) is what Amar Zeno was looking for. ;-)